# Count how many vertices in a vertex's neighbourhood have an attribute in igraph for R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a large graph (several, actually) in igraph—on the order of 100,000 vertices—and each vertex has an attribute which is either `true` or `false`. For each vertex, I would like to count how many of the vertices directly connected to it have the attribute. My current solution is the following function, which takes as its argument a graph.

```
attrcount <- function(g) {
  nb <- neighborhood(g,order=1)
  return(sapply(nb,function(x) {sum(V(g)$attr[x]}))
}
```

This returns a vector of counts which is off by 1 for vertices which have the attribute, but I can adjust this easily.

The problem is that this runs incredibly slowly, and it seems like there should be a fast way to do this, since, for instance, computing the degree of each vertex is practically instantaneous with `degree(g)`.

Am I doing this a stupid way?

As an example, suppose this was our graph.

```
set.seed(42)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(169081, 178058, type="gnm")
V(g)$att <- as.logical(rbinom(vcount(g), 1, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get.adjlist` to query all adjacent vertices, and then `sapply` (or `tapply` might be even faster) on this list to get the counts. It is also worth storing the attribute in a vector, because then you don't need to extract it all the time.

#### With sapply

```
system.time({
  al <- get.adjlist(g)
  att <- V(g)$att
  res <- sapply(al, function(x) sum(att[x]))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.571   0.005   0.576
```

#### With tapply

```
system.time({
  al <- get.adjlist(g)
  alv <- unlist(al)
  alf <- factor(rep(seq_along(al), sapply(al, length)),
                levels=seq_along(al))
  att <- V(g)$att
  res2 <- tapply(att[alv], alf, sum)
  res2[is.na(res2)] <- 0
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.121   0.020   1.144 

all(res == res2)
# TRUE
```

Somewhat a surprise to me, but the `tapply` solution is actually slower.

If this is still not enough, then I guess you can still make it faster by writing it in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out exactly how to do that. I edited the question to include something to work with

Comment: I'm trying this now `sapply(get.adjlist(g),function(x) sum(V(g)$att[x]))` which works for toy examples but is still excruciatingly slow on the full graph.

Comment: This graph is too small to benchmark. Please add a graph that is comparable to the one you have, e.g. it has the same degree dequence.  See `degree.sequence.game`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to include that data. Should I put a dropbox link to a text file or something?

Comment: No, just set the random seed and create a random graph with the same degree sequence as yours. See `degree` and `degree.sequence.game`.

Comment: yeah I see how to make that graph but I'm not sure what you mean by including that graph in the question. `degree.sequence.game(degree(proj_graph_jan))
IGRAPH U--- 169081 178058 -- Degree sequence random graph
+ attr: name (g/c), method (g/c)` gives a graph with the degree sequence, but how should I include this in the question?

Comment: You are right, degree sequence is a bad idea, but I have included a graph with the same number of vertices and edges, this should be good enough.

Comment: Amazing, this works perfectly. Thank you so much, you just saved me like 10 hours.

Comment: I have a bit of a followup question for you if you don't mind. In my graph, edges also have weights from 1 to around 30, and I would also like to compute the weighted sum the above computation, i.e. each `T` vertex in a neighbourhood of v contributes w where w is the edge weight. I can't figure out a nice way to do this. Should I ask this in a separate question?

Comment: Yes, ask a separate question please.

Comment: Alright, I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165452/counting-how-many-vertices-in-a-neighbourhood-have-a-given-attribute-with-edge-w

Answer (score 0):

For faster computation, use `get.adjacency` to pull the adjacency matrix, then multiply the matrix by the attribute vector using `%*%`:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(42)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1000, type = "gnm")
V(g)$att <- as.logical(rbinom(vcount(g), 1, 0.5))

system.time({
  ma   <- get.adjacency(g)
  att  <- V(g)$att
  res1 <- as.numeric(ma %*% att)
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.003   0.000   0.003
```

Compared to using `get.adjlist` and `sapply`:

```
system.time({
  al   <- get.adjlist(g)
  att  <- V(g)$att
  res2 <- sapply(al, function(x) sum(att[x]))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  9.733   0.243  10.107
```

After modifying the class of `res1`, the results vector is identical:

```
res1 <- as.numeric(res1)
identical(res1, res2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks to igraph storing adjacency matrices as `dgCMatrix-class` objects, which are sparse and therefore relatively small in `object.size`, this method should also be applicable to much larger graphs without too much overhead.