# Counting how many vertices in a neighbourhood have a given attribute with edge weights in igraph for R

Tags: r, igraph

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155365/count-how-many-vertices-in-a-vertexs-neighbourhood-have-an-attribute-in-igraph/23156809?noredirect=1#23156809). I have a very large graph, on the order of 100,000 vertices in igraph. Each vertex has an attribute `att` which is a logical value. Edges are weighted with positive integer weights. For each vertex v, I would like to sum the edge weights of edges that connect `v` to a vertex where `att=T`.

We can use the following as an example

```
set.seed(42)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(169081, 178058, type="gnm")
V(g)$att <- as.logical(rbinom(vcount(g), 1, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get, for each vertex `v,` the sum of edge weights of neighboring vertices with `att=T`. Gabor might have a more elegant way that is much faster.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(42)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(169081, 178058, type="gnm")
V(g)$att <- as.logical(rbinom(vcount(g), 1, 0.5))
E(g)$weight <- sample(10, ecount(g), replace=TRUE) #integer weights

sumEdgeWeightsOfEdgesFromVertexV<- function(v){
  totwt <- 0
  #get all neighbors of vertex v
  all_neighbors_of_v <- V(g)[nei(v)]
  #subset to those with att to be TRUE
  att_nei <- as.vector(all_neighbors_of_v[all_neighbors_of_v$att==TRUE])
  #sum all the weights, edge by edge
  for( ver in att_nei) {
    totwt <- totwt + E(g, c(v,ver))$weight
  }
  totwt
}  

# sapply(V(g), sumEdgeWeightsOfEdgesFromVertexV)
```